# Is there a way to refactor this code to make it more concise?

Tags: reactjs

The code works fine and the app runs very smooth. But for the if statement, I feel that there is a way I could refactor it down to be more concise? The else clause is fine I think, I'm just not totally sure how to do it. I'd like it to be as concise as possible, but I can't find a different way to write it.
The difference between the 2 is the p element, it's a message that displays, then disappears once you create the first li. So in my if block, I have some of the same code as in the else clause. All the code in the if block is needed to run the app at the start. Thanks for any help!

```
 if(guests.length < 1){
       return(

     <div className="App">
       <Header />
       <AddGuest
       guest={props.guest}
       addGuest={props.addGuest}
       updatePendingGuestValue={props.updatePendingGuestValue}
       pendingGuest={props.pendingGuest}
       />

       <p className='intro-message'>Invite some friends and family! Confirm your guests,
       change their names if needed, remove the guest or filter through your guest who
       have/have not confirmed. Get started above!</p>

       <PendingGuestLi
         pendingGuest={props.pendingGuest} />
     </div>
 )
  }else{
     return(    
     <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <AddGuest
      guest={props.guest}
      addGuest={props.addGuest}
      updatePendingGuestValue={props.updatePendingGuestValue}
      pendingGuest={props.pendingGuest}
      />

     <div className='filter-checkbox-container'>
       <label className='filter-guests-label'>Hide all unconfirmed guest
         <input type='checkbox' className='filter-guests-checkbox'
         value={props.filterUnconfirmedGuest} onChange={props.toggleFilterUnconfirmedGuest} />
       </label>
     </div>

     <GuestList
       guest={props.guest}
       toggleGuestConfirmed={props.toggleGuestConfirmed}
       toggleEditGuest={props.toggleEditGuest}
       editGuest={props.editGuest}
       removeGuest={props.removeGuest}
       filterUnconfirmedGuest={props.filterUnconfirmedGuest}
        />
     <PendingGuestLi
       pendingGuest={props.pendingGuest} />
   </div>
     )
   }
```

Thank you for checking it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separating what stays the same and what changes and placing it inside a block.

```
  return(
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <AddGuest
        guest={props.guest}
        addGuest={props.addGuest}
        updatePendingGuestValue={props.updatePendingGuestValue}
        pendingGuest={props.pendingGuest}
      />
      {(guests.length < 1) ?
          <p className='intro-message'>
            Invite some friends and family! Confirm your guests,
            change their names if needed, remove the guest or filter through your guest who
            have/have not confirmed. Get started above!
          </p>
        :
         <Fragment>
          <div className='filter-checkbox-container'>
            <label className='filter-guests-label'>Hide all unconfirmed guest
              <input type='checkbox' className='filter-guests-checkbox'
              value={props.filterUnconfirmedGuest} onChange={props.toggleFilterUnconfirmedGuest} />
            </label>
          </div>
          <GuestList
            guest={props.guest}
            toggleGuestConfirmed={props.toggleGuestConfirmed}
            toggleEditGuest={props.toggleEditGuest}
            editGuest={props.editGuest}
            removeGuest={props.removeGuest}
            filterUnconfirmedGuest={props.filterUnconfirmedGuest}
             />
          </Fragment>
      }
      <PendingGuestLi
        pendingGuest={props.pendingGuest} />
      </div>
  )
```

Comment: This is incorrect, you can't have an if statement inside jsx

Comment: Just to build on this answer, all that you need to do is look for the commonalities between the true and false cases. This helps you narrow down the range that conditional statement really applies to.